# Connection is busy with result of an other hstmt in C#

Tags: c#

so this is my code, 
i don't really know why it works in other programs, this code is standard !!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
    {
        String query = "***";
        OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
        DbCommand.CommandText = query;
        try
        {
            OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

            do
            {
                int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
                if (fCount > 0)
                {
                    while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        using (OdbcConnection DbConnect = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
                        {
                            OdbcCommand DbCom = DbConnect.CreateCommand();
                            query = System.String.Format("***", DbReader.GetInt16(0));
                            DbCom.CommandText = query;
                            try
                            {
                                DbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (OdbcException ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Executing the query2 failed.");
                                Console.WriteLine("The OdbcCommand returned the following message");
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Query affected row(s)");
                }
            }
            while (DbReader.NextResult());

            DbReader.Close();
        }
        catch (OdbcException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing the query1 failed.");
            Console.WriteLine("The OdbcCommand returned the following message");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me the following error, I've tried so many deplacement of the start and and connection but without any goog result.

CODE EDITED :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
            {
                DbConnection.Open();
                OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
                DbCommand.CommandText = "select ID from Table where ID not in (select IdDA from Seconde)";
                try
                {
                    OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    do
                    {
                        int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
                        if (fCount > 0)
                        {
                            while (DbReader.Read())
                            {
                                using (OdbcConnection DbConnect = new OdbcConnection("DSN=savior"))
                                {
                                    DbConnect.Open();
                                    OdbcCommand DbCom = DbConnect.CreateCommand();
                                    DbCom.CommandText = System.String.Format("INSERT into Seconde(IdDA,Validee) values({0},'oui')", DbReader.GetInt16(0));
                                    try
                                    {
                                        DbCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                    catch (OdbcException ex)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Executing the query2 failed.");
                                        Console.WriteLine("The OdbcCommand returned the following message");
                                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Query affected no row(s)");
                        }
                    }
                    while (DbReader.NextResult());
                }
                catch (OdbcException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing the query1 failed.");
                    Console.WriteLine("The OdbcCommand returned the following message");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: For one thing, you're keeping going even if you fail to open the connection. You haven't told us *which* line fails, either.

Comment: I have edited the code(in top) but without any result !!
i thinks i've done what you tell !?

Comment: Well now your code doesn't open either connection at all. You've also made the existing answers seem odd, as they refer to code which is no longer in the question. (It would have been better to add that as *extra* code within the question.) You also still appear to be using string formatting for the SQL, which is still a very very bad idea.

Comment: sorry, for ridiculos question but why i am not openning any connection ??
I am confused, I have to finish test and send this work in 40min.

Comment: Try to find calls to `DbConnection.Open` and `DbConnect.Open`. Those calls certainly aren't in the code in the question.

Comment: **NEVER** only catch the Exception.Messag!!! Catch always the whole Exception. In your case replace `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);` with `Console.WriteLine(ex.toString());` and post it

Comment: code edited but no results and no errors !!

Comment: for parametrized sql queries, I'll do that when I'll have time.

Comment: @tp1: So have you debugged into your code? If not, do so now.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
OdbcCommand DbCommand1 = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
OdbcCommand DbCommand2 = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
```

... creates two commands on the same connection, and tries to use them at the same time (inserting using one command while reading from the other). I suspect you'd be more successful if you created two connections.

Additionally:

- *Please* don't include values in your SQL statement through string manipulation. Use parameterized SQL instead, otherwise you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), conversion issues, and brittle code.
- Use `using` statements to automatically close connections, commands and readers regardless of success or failure
- When you catch an exception, it's very rarely a good idea to just keep going. For example, if you fail to open the connection, you're still going to try to read from the database. That's just asking for trouble.
- Usually local variables in C# are camelCased instead of PascalCased. It's a good idea to follow the normal conventions of the language, to aid others who will be reading your code.

Comment: when I catch an exception how can I close this action ??

Comment: @tp1: I'm afraid I don't know what your comment is asking.

Answer (score 1):

On line 18 of what you've posted, you execute a command against your connection:

```
OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
```

Then, while that reader is still open, on line 30 you execute another command on the same connection:

```
DbCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can't do this; only one command can be executing at a time on a given connection. Whilst that reader is open, you're not able to do anything else on the connection. You'd have to close the reader first, which given your scenario means you're going to have to copy all the data you need out of your reader, close the reader, and then start looping through and issuing the subsequent commands.

Answer (score 0):

Every command object should be explicitly disposed.

I met this error in a different scenario. I was doing only one command at a time and still getting this *connection busy*. *MARS_Connection=yes* did not resolve the issue. After analyzing the trace in *MS SQL Server Profiler* I discovered that prepared statements were not released right after use. The `exec sp_unprepare` messages were appearing some time later. Then I did a change in my program and disposed `OdbcCommand` directly after use (`Dispose()`). After that I had `sp_unprepared` messages immediately after insert statements. And I was no longer seeing those random errors.

The most tricky thing was trying to dispose `OdbcAdapter`. This code did not work:

```
var daOut = new OdbcDataAdapter("select top 1 * from " + sTableTo, cmdOut);
...
daOut.Dispose(); // Not enough.
```

And this one did:

```
var cmdOut = new OdbcCommand("select top 1 * from " + sTableTo, m_connOut);
var daOut = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmdOut);
...
daOut.Dispose();
cmdOut.Dispose(); // Oh yeah!
```

So sometimes you need to extract the command object just to make sure you dispose it explicitly. And after all these thing, I could even turn off the *MARS_Connection* flag.